# what reference of airfoil is used to define lift and drag?

Tags: aerodynamics

On aerofoil section, the force of lift acts perpendicular to, and the force drags acts parallel to the :

A: chord line
B: flight path
C: aerofoil section upper surface 
D: longitudinal axis

Comment: Free stream flow. You should have a word with your instructor.

Comment: why are you hesitating between all the possibility? It recommend you read the airfoil section of [how it flies?](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html#fig-airfoil-terms)

Comment: I change the title of  your question so that it looks like a question. feel free to edit  again if it does not reflect what you wanted to know

Comment: @Jimmy The instructor expects B (flight path) as the right answer. Which is correct if there is no wind.

Comment: @PeterKampf Flight path is inertial. It has no bearing on aerodynamics. Even if we are talking about a wind tunnel case where the section is constrained, flight path is very poor wording; pitch attitude would be marginally better in that case.

Comment: @Jimmy: So what? The air flows towards the aircraft in exactly the opposite direction to the direction of the aircraft's movement. That is what counts.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Not sure what you mean. For a wind-less relationship, $\alpha=\theta - \gamma$. $\gamma$ being the flight path angle. $\alpha$ is what counts here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_dynamics_(fixed-wing_aircraft)#Short-period_pitch_oscillation for illustration.

Comment: @PeterKämpf is correct, there should be an answer about the relative wind. He is also correct that the answer should be "B", we apply the CASA approach which is "the least incorrect" response.

Comment: @PeterKämpf, why does pitch angle have to be zero?   You could be pitched 45 degrees nose low in a dive and drag will be opposite to, and parallel with, your flight path.  What am I missing?

Comment: P.S.  Where were the homework police on this one?!

Comment: @MichaelHall I don't know why I said this. Lift and drag are defined in the aerodynamic system, and this is in turn defined by the direction of flow. Pitch angle could be anything.

Comment: So @JZYL, what point are you trying to make in asserting above that pitch attitude is a "marginally better" term, (than flight path) in describing the vector opposite to drag?

Comment: @MichaelHall The main takeaway is the choices are all wrong.

Comment: @JZYL, that isn't helpful in the least.  If you think you can clear this up then please provide an answer and not murky criticism.  (keep in mind the context of the question)

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic question, and I give you the answer from the initial pages of a aerodynamic learning textbook.

The  is presented in next figure:

[image: Resultant aerodynamic force and the components into which it splits]

Where:

- L: lift: component of R (resultant force) perpendicular to air stream,
- D: drag: component of R parallel with the air stream,
- N: Normal Force: component of R perpendicular to chord,
- A: Axial Force: component of R parallel with chord,

For further information you can refer to [Anderson's Aerodynamic book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073398101).

Comment: Good diagram.  This is very interesting as it presents a realistic representation of the forward component of lift (relative to perpendicular of wing) created by airflow over the leading edge curve at a higher AOA.  This was noticed in drag studies, producing a negative drag coefficient!  This is also a great illustration of areodynamic center through one point as AOA (potentially) changes.  Correct answer - B.